# How to do two proportion prop.test for each single row in a data frame?

Tags: r, proportions, z-test

The result produce the same p-value for each row, while the p-value looks different when I calculate each row seperately.

I am trying to test the different between the baseline and endline proportions, here is the data

```
  group n_Baseline n_Endline sample_Baseline sample_Endline
  <chr>      <int>     <int>           <dbl>          <dbl>
1 A            164       158             305            273
2 B             89        65             131            106
3 C             59        68             118            108
4 D             52        48              90             84
5 E            141       107             224            186
```

I tried the instruction like below:

```
df$P_Values <- apply(df, 1, function(x) prop.test(x = c(df$n_Baseline, df$n_Endline), n = c(df$sample_Baseline, df$sample_Endline))$p.value).
```

The outcome has the same p-value for each row:

```
 group n_Baseline n_Endline sample_Baseline sample_Endline P_Values
  <chr>      <int>     <int>           <dbl>          <dbl>    <dbl>
1 A            164       158             305            273    0.109
2 B             89        65             131            106    0.109
3 C             59        68             118            108    0.109
4 D             52        48              90             84    0.109
5 E            141       107             224            186    0.109
```

However, when I do this seperately for each row, the pvalue is very different. For example in the 1st row:

```
prop.test(x = c(164, 158), n = c(305, 273))
```

Output:

> 2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction
>
> data:  c(164, 158) out of c(305, 273)
> X-squared = 0.82448, df = 1, p-value = 0.3639
> alternative hypothesis: two.sided
> 95 percent confidence interval:
> -0.12552283  0.04342351
> sample estimates:
> prop 1    prop 2
> 0.5377049 0.5787546

Why and how do I get the exact p-value for each row instead of the same one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably via `rowwise` calculations inside `dplyr` from the tidyverse

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(pval = prop.test(x = c(n_Baseline, n_Endline), 
                          n = c(sample_Baseline, sample_Endline))$p.value)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   group n_Baseline n_Endline sample_Baseline sample_Endline   pval
#>   <chr>      <int>     <int>           <int>          <int>  <dbl>
#> 1 A            164       158             305            273 0.364 
#> 2 B             89        65             131            106 0.355 
#> 3 C             59        68             118            108 0.0676
#> 4 D             52        48              90             84 1.00  
#> 5 E            141       107             224            186 0.310
```

If you want to stick to base R, then you *can* use `apply`, but your syntax for `apply` is not correct here. The function in `apply` takes each row of your data frame as a vector and calls it `x`. You then need to use the vector `x` as the elements inside `prop.test`, but instead you are passing whole columns from your data frame to `prop.test`. Since you are passing the same thing each time, you get the same (wrong) p value each time.

In addition, because your first column is a character vector, each row will be coerced into a character vector, so the maths won't work unless you skip the first column in your `apply` call by using `df[-1]`

The correct use of `apply` would be:

```r
df$pval <- apply(df[-1], 1, \(x) prop.test(x = x[1:2], n = x[3:4])$p.value)

df
#>   group n_Baseline n_Endline sample_Baseline sample_Endline       pval
#> 1     A        164       158             305            273 0.36387328
#> 2     B         89        65             131            106 0.35495949
#> 3     C         59        68             118            108 0.06758474
#> 4     D         52        48              90             84 1.00000000
#> 5     E        141       107             224            186 0.30960338
```

---

**Data from question in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(group = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), n_Baseline = c(164L, 
89L, 59L, 52L, 141L), n_Endline = c(158L, 65L, 68L, 48L, 107L
), sample_Baseline = c(305L, 131L, 118L, 90L, 224L), sample_Endline = c(273L, 
106L, 108L, 84L, 186L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```